# What Is The Best Way To Run Continous Pings On Multiple IP Addresses

Tags: vb.net, loops, ping

I have an application that currently runs a ping against about 60 different gateways to monitor internet uptime for my clients as I want to know if their internet drops out before they do.  So currently my application runs through a loop starting at the first one (runs 4 pings) waits 2 seconds and then moves on to the next gateway address.  I have then implemented some code to retry a number of times if the ping results as a failure as I want to be 100% sure that their connection is down before sending an alert.

The problem with this method is that it takes around 1 or 2 minutes (or sometimes longer) before the same gateway is scanned again, meaning that if the connection was to drop out straight after a ping, I wouldn't know for nearly 2 minutes.  I know this sounds miniscule but I would much rather instant alerting to my team so they can act on this immediately.

Therefore, my question is: Would it be better (and what would be the impact) of running 60 separate pings (on different threads maybe) instead of cycling through each one.  This way I could run a continuous ping on each gateway at the same time.  However, I am worried about performance impact on my application and if it will create too much load on the system.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks

**EDIT**

I have created the following code which works but seems to impact a single processor core heavily and whilst this method works without error, it seems to deem the GUI as in-responsive soon after:

```
Public Sub PingHost()
    Try
        GatewayScanning = True
        For i As Integer = 0 To Gateways.Count - 1
            Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf CheckHostOnline)
            t.IsBackground = True
            t.Start(Gateways(i))
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorTrap(ex, "OfflineClientHandler: PingHost()")
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub CheckHostOnline(ByVal gw As Object)
    Try
        Dim _gateway As Gateway_Object = DirectCast(gw, Gateway_Object)
        Dim pingSender As New Ping()
        Dim options As New PingOptions()
        'Dim averageTime As Integer
        Dim OfflinePingCount As Integer = 0

        ' Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
        ' but change the fragmentation behavior.
        options.DontFragment = False
        options.Ttl = 128

        ' Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        Dim data As String = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        Dim buffer() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
        Dim timeout As Integer = 3000

        Do While Not GatewayScanning = False
            Dim reply As PingReply = pingSender.Send(_gateway.Gateway, timeout, buffer, options)

            If reply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
                Dim resultTime As Integer = GetMs(CInt(reply.RoundtripTime))
                _gateway.Status = "ONLINE"
                _gateway.Result = resultTime
            Else
                OfflinePingCount += 1
                If OfflinePingCount < (My.Settings.OfflinePingCycleNumber * 4) Then
                    _gateway.Status = "TIMEOUT"
                    _gateway.Result = -1
                Else
                    _gateway.Status = "OFFLINE"
                    _gateway.Result = -1
                End If
            End If

            SyncLock class_OfflineGateways
                class_OfflineGateways.UpdateListView(_gateway)
            End SyncLock

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Loop
        pingSender.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorTrap(ex, "OfflineClientHandler: CheckHostOnline()")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Are your clients' services so mission critical that a __theoretical__ two minute lead on downtime is essential? Consider the method that you or your clients' are informed. For example, will they even get your message immediately (or within two minutes, 10 minutes, an hour..) when you send out that email, text message, what have you? Are these services which have dedicated response personnel available 24 hours a day?

Comment: What if you create a thread for each gateway that has established an accepted connection? That way you can allow each thread to manage itself individually, as far as the timing. From there you can have a shared object that a thread can invoke to update a Boolean flag indicating if the connection is still alive.

Comment: @JustinRyan It does become mission critical when the gateway involves electronic payment systems.  Try standing in line at a busy retail outlet when their payment systems go offline and tell me that 2 minutes isn't a long time!  :)

Comment: Do you have a program instaled on the clients computer or are you talking about a bank card payment device with its own conection?

Comment: @Riples If you have determined that a shorter interval is necessary, that's fine. My point was to encourage you to perhaps broaden your scope of the potential issues. I'll agree that from a customer's perspective, two minutes is an eternity, but I would evaluate instead the real problem that caused the downtime, as opposed to applying a bandage in the form of notification. Consider also that a ping only tells you if a connection is sound, but will not inform you of unresponsive web services, for example.

Comment: A quick search found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926773/do-ping-requests-put-a-load-on-a-server), which may be of use to you.

Comment: @JustinRyan Thanks for the feedback - much appreciated.  My scenario involves a number of retail clients that all run integrated payment systems through a payment gateway.  If their ISP link goes down it causes a large influx of support calls my way.  In reality I can't really do much about it, however, I can at least prepare my team for what's to come!  :)  It will also give me some logging as to slow traffic as well as frequency of downtime which are all good support tools for the support desk.  I think (based on your link) I will look at a single gateway ping per thread.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to cycle through the 60 IPs on different threads, and require a five-second (or some amount of time) delay before beginning the cycle again.

Another way is to us asynchronous pings instead of separate threads.

Last time I did this, I ended up using a single thread with 10 ms sleep delay between pings. There were too many ping failures whenever I bunched them together, either with threads or asynch pings. I never did figure out whether the problem was on the server end or on the destination network.

Here's a class I used to ping a list of IP addresses. It (and a bunch of other stuff) ran as a service on an ISP server. (I notice I still have the backgroundworker declared, although it's no longer used.)

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Class pingGroup
' used to ping each IP in Targets

Public Targets As New List(Of IPAddress)
Public sectorID As Integer
Public nErrors As Integer = 0
Public Timeout As Integer = pingTimeout

Public PingLog As New List(Of String)
Public PingAvg As Integer = -2 ' -2 = uninit, -1 = error, else average ms excluding the slowest
Public PingTime As DateTime

Public pingCount As Integer = 0
Public pingStarts As Integer = 0
Dim msTotal As Integer = 0

Dim WithEvents bkgPing As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Public Sub New(ByVal groupSectorID As Integer)
sectorID = groupSectorID
End Sub

Public Sub Ping()
' run a pingtest once, adding the result incrementally

Dim ip As IPAddress
Dim reply As NetworkInformation.PingReply
Dim ms As Integer

PingTime = Now

If PingLog.Count <= 0 Then PingLog.Add(Format(Now, "G") & " Ping Test")

For Each ip In Targets
  Using pPing As New NetworkInformation.Ping
    Try
      pingStarts = pingStarts + 1
      reply = pPing.Send(ip, Timeout)
      If reply.Status = NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        ms = reply.RoundtripTime
        pingCount = pingCount + 1
        msTotal = msTotal + ms
        If pingCount > 0 Then PingAvg = msTotal / pingCount
        PingLog.Add(reply.Address.ToString & " " & ms)
      Else
        nErrors = nErrors + 1
        PingLog.Add(Format(Now, "G") & " ---Ping Error: " & ip.ToString & " " & reply.Status.ToString)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
      nErrors = nErrors + 1
      PingLog.Add(Format(Now, "G") & " ===Ping Error: " & ip.ToString & " " & ex.Message)
      End Try
    End Using
  Thread.Sleep(10)
  Next ip

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Xpda - Do you have an example how to do this?  I have written my code to run a continuous ping, but I am having issues on creating 60 separate threads to run this as I need to pass in parameters to my sub routine.

Comment: I added some code I've used in the past. I decided against asynch or multithreading.

Comment: Create a class which receives the IP address to ping, having functionality to log ping status for this IP and perform other action for this IP.
Then create thread pool for list of IP address, for each IP address create an instance of class and run in a thread and at last wait for all threads to end. This will keep the application running.

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal I have edited my post to show the code I have thus far.  However, whilst it seems to work as I need, it is creating an impact to the processor and causing GUI lag.

Comment: Try putting application.doevents() in an inner loop.